# Userint AppCrash Kernelbase.dll any ideas

Tags: windows-7, windows, 64-bit, login, user-profiles

Every logon gives me an appcrash from userinit.

I have rebuit the profile.
I have run SFC and DMIS numerous times.
The issue appears for all new users, but other existing profiles work fine.

Also getting periodic temp profiles.

Anyone got anything else to try?

**Problem signature:**

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: userinit.exe
  Application Version:  6.1.7601.17514
  Application Timestamp:    4ce79e9a
  Fault Module Name:    KERNELBASE.dll
  Fault Module Version: 6.1.7601.23714
  Fault Module Timestamp:   58bf8a2e
  Exception Code:   e06d7363
  Exception Offset: 000000000001a06d
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
  Locale ID:    2057
  Additional Information 1: 79d2
  Additional Information 2: 79d211c59d30f917c8be53e4733342ab
  Additional Information 3: fdee
  Additional Information 4: fdeea42c143e31f40dad4cf81bcb57cd

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

Comment: [create a crash dump](https://pastebin.com/zKuJvw57), zip the dmp, upload the zip to OneDrive and paste the share link here. I'll analyze the crash dump to see

Comment: You may copy and paste kernelbase.dll from WinSxS folder and try to reboot.